# PHP: JSON decoding

Tags: php, json

I keep getting stuck trying to decode some json I'm getting back from a db query:

My result =

```
{"queryResults":[{"id":"1","pageName":"home","blurb":"<p>knowInk Publishing is a Media Professional Services firm dedicated to integrating existing publications into the technology of today, introduce the publications of the future and provide traditional services for the print industry.<\/p> \r\n<p>From e-publishing, e-singles, mobile, web and print design and development, printing on demand and our editorial services we can provide a nuts to soup solution to your publishing needs.<\/p>\r\nLearn more about how KI can help you.","imgPath":"images\/img_homepage.jpg"},{"id":"3","pageName":"about","blurb":"This is where the about text would go. ","imgPath":"images\/img_about.jpg"},{"id":"4","pageName":"services","blurb":"This is where we would talk about the services we can provide","imgPath":"images\/img_services.jpg"},{"id":"5","pageName":"marketplace","blurb":"This is where we will discuss our marketplace, where you can buy and sell things","imgPath":"images\/img_marketplace.jpg"}]}
```

I put the json into a session var and am able to retrieve it. But when I go to dig into it I am getting stuck. Here's my PHP code:

```
print $_SESSION['basicPageHTML']; //works fine, gives me the json above

$code = json_decode($_SESSION['basicPageHTML']); 
print count($code->queryResults); //this seems right, gives me 4
foreach($code->queryResults as $thisKey => $thisValue) { 
     //I can't do anything here.
}
```

I've been away from PHP for a bit and it's funny how you forget so quickly...

Comment: Also, since you've been out of the php: Instead of sessions, serialization might be more secure. It does, however, depend on the scenario, I can't see enough of the code to determine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did it correctly the first time. You just need to continue doing it.

```
echo $thisValue->pageName;
```